# Science fiction book about a near miss with an asteroid or comet and the aftermath

Tags: story-identification, novel

Years ago I read a book about a near miss by an asteroid or comet.
I don’t remember the name or author but I remember three things.

Travelers go to Chicago and find it empty and Lake Michigan had tilted and the flood ran through the city.

Astronauts that were stranded came back and ended up landing their capsule in Disneyland.

And at the very end, train travel was the best way to get around and two of the characters were on their way to the dedication of the new Capitol building in DC.

Comment: Please visit https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info for prompts that you can answer to make your question better.

Comment: [Lucifer's Hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucifer%27s_Hammer) has a lot of these tropes

Comment: Thanks! I’ve read Lucifer’s Hammer and it’s not that book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it have been Lucifer's Hammer by Larry Nivens and Jerry Pournelle?

That book had massive destruction on Earth and many extreme right-wing political commentaries. (One character explicitly thinks that despite the deaths of billions, on the bright side feminism is gone).

Comment: That’s true. I’ve been trying to find this book forever.

Comment: Also, the astronauts had no one to guide them back and they end of landing in a devastated Disney World. Tsunamis had crossed Florida and the book talked about resident waiting to go back to “their beloved peninsula”.

Comment: There's no visit to Chicago that I can remember though.

Comment: No Disney World or Florida either IIRC.  Most of Lucifer's Hammer is set in California.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I agree. All the stuff about Chicago, Lake Michigan, and trains running to DC doesn't sound like *Lucifer's Hammer* to me. Must be some other novel.

Comment: @Gregg: While this one might not be a match, the way to accept an answer is to click on the checkmark by the voting buttons.